# studentized CIs for a correlation using package boot

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to get the studentized CIs for a correlation coefficient using bootstrap. This is what I have now, I have not come up with a way around to get the correct studentized CIs. I'm using the R extension in spss, but it shouldn't affect the usability.

```
Begin Program R.
rm(list=ls())
library(boot)
allData <- spssdata.GetDataFromSPSS(variables =c('compsales','T003000_mean'))
dict <-
spssdictionary.GetDictionaryFromSPSS(variables=c('compsales','T003000_mean'))

allData <- na.omit(allData)

cortest <- cor.test(allData$compsales,allData$T003000_mean)

pearson <- function(d, i){
d2 <- d[i,]
return(cor(d2$compsales,d2$T003000_mean))
}
bootcorr <- boot(allData, pearson, R=1200)
bootcorr
boot.ci(bootcorr,type = c("norm","basic", "perc","bca"),conf = .95)
End Program.
```

To try to get it I wrote the function as:

```
pearson <- function(d, i){
d2 <- d[i,]
return(cor(d2$compsales,d2$T003000_mean), var(d2$compsales,d2$T003000_mean))
}
```

and in the `boot.ci` as:

```
boot.ci(bootcorr,type = "all",conf = .95)
```

But the vector for the variances are all N/As

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the correlation and variance as a vector:

```
pearson <- function(d, i){
d2 <- d[i,]
return(
c(cor(d2$compsales,d2$T003000_mean),var(d2$compsales),var(d2$T003000_mean))
)
}

library(boot)
data = data.frame(compsales=runif(100),T003000_mean=runif(100))
bo =boot(data,pearson,R=99)

boot.ci(bo,type="stud")
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 99 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = bo, type = "stud")

Intervals : 
Level    Studentized     
95%   (-0.1593,  0.3648 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some studentized intervals may be unstable
```